# Remove numbers from strings in a LIST

Tags: r, list

I have here a small list of strings:

```
> dput(test)
list(c("jason", "mid1920s", "living2018"))
```

I want to remove words with numbers so that the list only contains "jason".
I've tried this code to no avail. (I would like a solution to apply my function in a list, not a vector or dataframe)

```
test[[1]] <- lapply(test[[1]], gsub("[[:digit:]]+", "", .))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the use of `lapply` in the OP's code and the `list` is of `length` 1.  In that case, it could be extracted and apply the `gsub`

```
test[[1]] <- gsub("\\d+", "", test[[1]]
```

Also, in the OP's code there is a `.` which is incorrect

```
lapply(test[[1]], gsub("[[:digit:]]+", "", .))
```

It should be

```
lapply(test, function(x) gsub("[[:digit:]]+", "", x))
```

But, if the intention is to `filter` out the elements that have a number, then `grep` would be useful as `gsub` removes the substring  i.e. one or more digits (`\\d+`) from the string.

```
test[[1]] <- test[[1]][!grepl("\\d+", test[[1]])]
```

---

In addition, if there are many `list` elements, we can use `lapply`

```
lapply(test, function(x) x[!grepl("\\d+", x)])
```

Comment: re-reading the OP, i think this is slightly wrong -- I think OP wants output as `'jason'` (so `grep` not `gsub`)

Comment: (no vote from me, just speculating)

Comment: @akrun The downvote (not from me) may have had something to do that your answer acts on a vector, not a list.  But the list in the OP is trivial, because it just contains a vector of words, on which the OP is actually focusing.